# Помогите разобраться в hover

Tags: html, css, css3

Подскажите как реализовать, чтобы при наведении курсора на fontawesome, текст пропадал, а когда курсор убираешь с иконки он обратно появлялся

```css
.soc{
 position: absolute;
 padding-top:26%;
 right: 5%;
}

.soc i{
 color:#FFF;
}
.facebook{
 position: absolute;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 20px;
 color:#78D77C;
 padding-right:300px;
 padding-top:26%;
}
.soc i:hover .soc .facebook{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="soc">
      <i id="fac" class="fab fa-facebook fa-3x"></i>
      <div class="facebook">
      facebook
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Перекрасить в прозрачный?

Comment: Посмотрите мой код, пожалуйста, у меня не срабатывает hover. Не могу понять по какой причине

Comment: У вас ошибка в селекторе, вам нужно написать `i:hover + .facebook`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.soc {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 26%;
  right: 5%;
}

.soc i {
  color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #78D77C;
  padding-right: 300px;
  padding-top: 26%;
}

.soc i:hover + .facebook {
  /*display: none;*/
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="soc">
  <i id="fac" class="fab fa-facebook fa-3x">AAAAA</i>
  <div class="facebook">
    facebook
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое